# Lookup String from File and Use as Filter

Tags: python, dataframe

I have some reference file which contains the conditions that's needed for tagging records in a data frame.

REFERENCE FILE

```
GROUP,CONDITION
1,df['a'].find('abc')
2,df['d'].find('def')
3,df['g'].find('ghi')
```

I want to check on my main data whether the string exists in the TEXTFIELD column and tag it to its respective group.

MAIN DATA

```
ID,TEXTFIELD
A,fsadflnashdfp**abc**asfa
B,**ghi**dsfasdfasfqegdfsd
C,orjtorenblmflvdfg**def**
```

DESIRED RESULT

```
ID,GROUP
A,1
B,3
C,2
```

How do I call the function inside the reference file? Or is there any other cleaner way to do this?

Current script looks like this which I believe I'm doing something wrong and throws the error KeyError: "df['TEXTFIELD'].find('abc')"

```
x = [
     [1, "df['TEXTFIELD'].find('abc')"], 
     [2, "df['TEXTFIELD'].find('def')"], 
     [3, "df['TEXTFIELD'].find('ghi')"]

] 

y = [
     ['A','fsadflnashdfpabcasfa'],
     ['B','ghidsfasdfasfqegdfsd'],
     ['C','orjtorenblmflvdfgdef ']
]

df_ref = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=["GROUP","CONDITION"])
df = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=["ID","TEXTFIELD"])

condition = df_ref.loc[0,'CONDITION']

df_out = df[condition]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already, some example of your code?

Comment: Is this a general question of how to separate conditions and data, or are you tied to this specific format?

Comment: I've updated my post to include the sample script which I believe is throwing some syntax issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so there are 3 things wrong with your question, if I got it right:

1-

```
df_ref = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=["GROUP","CONDITION"])
df = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=["ID","TEXTFIELD"])   # LOOK AT ME
```

I believe in the second line above, you actually meant `y`, instead of `x`, so it should be:

```
df_ref = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=["GROUP","CONDITION"])
df = pd.DataFrame(y,columns=["ID","TEXTFIELD"])
                # |  <- right here
```

2-

```
df['TEXTFIELD'].find('abc')
```

`find` is not a method of DataFrame, but you can achieve what you want with [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['TEXTFIELD'].str.contains('abc')
```

3-

```
df_ref.loc[0,'CONDITION']
```

This will return `"df['TEXTFIELD'].str.contains('abc')"`, notice this is a `string`, if you call `df["df['TEXTFIELD'].str.contains('abc')"]` it will give you a key error because it doesn't know what that string is. You want to do a boolean mask with the *expression* of that string, for that, you can use `eval`:

```
df[eval(condition)]
```

And it will give the result you want:

```
  ID             TEXTFIELD
0  A  fsadflnashdfpabcasfa
```

Obs.: I know people will throw eggs at me for suggesting the use of `eval`, it is a great security threat, so I only recommend using it if you are **certain** about whats on your file. It will solve your problem though...

Comment: Thanks for resolving my noob problem. Btw, are there any alternatives to eval if it raises some unsafe practices?

Comment: You could have 3 columns in your file, one with the column name you want to match, and one with the substring to be matched. If you can't change the file, you could load it into a DF and create two new columns as I described, maybe using Regex to match what you expect.